# google chrome doesn't show css style

Tags: css, google-chrome

when i inspect **some** elements in my site with google chrome 21 - i can see only elements, but i cant see some  styles.
 like

```
.content
{
}
```

if i check this with firebug i can see styles
like

```
.content
{
 color:white;
 font-size:12px;
}
```

the strange thing is google chrome show page correctly like FF and IE. when i click css link in google chrome i can see a broken image instead of css. 
i have checked css with css validator and there is no problem with my css.
what is problem?

Answer (score 2):

It's  `font-size` not  `fint-size`. Fix the typo and it will probably work.

Comment: sorry. my mistake.i edited my question.i said "i have checked css with css validator and there is no problem with my css"

Comment: Impossible to tell with the given information. Do you have any styles that could be overriding this one? Is it only this style? If not do the styles have anything in common? Does it always happen in Chrome?

Comment: some styles are over overrided and have this problem. i can see this problem only on my site.

Answer (score 0):

i hope this answer help someone:

i find this error in google chrome console:

> Resource interpreted as **Image** but transferred with MIME type
>   **text/css**

and a link to my css file.
this is why i get broken image when i click on css file as i mentioned in my question.

thanks to this [link](http://intertwinesys.com/2011/01/04/remove-custom-image-header-wordpress-child-theme/)
i found that i have a style

```
background:url('') // probably problem with background without image url,although css validator, validate it
```

and replaced it with

```
background:none.
```

at now i can see all styles in google chrome inspector and i see a css file when i click on css link.